# GeoServer's ImageMosaic and GeoTIFFjs

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

I have a selection of DSM/DTM data saved as smaller GeoTIFF files with an XML, proj file. I'm currently using the ImageMosaic feature on geoserver and serving them with WMS to a JavaScript/TypeScript front end.

I'm using the library [Geotiffjs](https://geotiffjs.github.io/) to process them into an array (we intend to do calculations with it via a front end tool) but I am only recieving the normalised data (min 0, max 255) with what seems to be no relevant metadata to rescale to the actual values.

Has anyone had a similar issue, or experience with this combination of techniques?

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: Is it possible to serve ImageMosaic via WFS/ WCS? or would this require another format. Apologies, I'm quite new to GIS.

Comment: You should be able to use WCS in much the same way you are using WMS.  If it doesn't work, please add details to your question showing the exact query and response. I don't think WFS is going to help much for this specific problem.